# How to keep listening for a request at the same time process another request in python

Tags: json, api, flask, heroku, ticket-system

So, it'a little complicated.

**What I am trying to do:**

1. Hosting an app on heroku and listening for webhooks sent by a messaging app (in JSON format) and saving them to a Database(SQLite3).
2. Use that Database to generate ticket on zoho desk.
3. If the ticket status is open I'll update the ticket with the new message otherwise I create a new ticket.
4. Overall it includes two processes:  Listening for webhooks and creating a ticket

**My problem/worries:**

1. I am able to listen for the webhooks but the problem I am facing is that when I am creating a ticket how can the same script listen for webhooks or vice and versa.
2. I have no idea how I can make these things so that while updating/creating a ticket I should be able to receive webhooks.

Sample code to listen to webhooks(JSON files sent via POST method).

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def respond():
    print(request.json);
    return Response(status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your process is not quite clear. Per your statement

1. You receive a message (via webhooks)
2. Then you go and generate a ticket
3. If the ticket status is open, you'll update the ticket with the message from step 1

   **Comment** - *if you generated a ticket in step 2, then why won't this ticket status be open? A new ticket should have an open status, right?*
4. If the ticket status is Not open, you'll create a new ticket

   **Comment** - *But you said you were generating a ticket in step 2?*

Maybe I misunderstood what you typed but can you shed more light on your process?

Comment: I will rewrite what I wanted to do:

1. I receive a message (via webhooks)
2. I check if a ticket by that person already exists with status = open. 
3. If status = open: I will update the ticket with the new message.
4. Else: I will generate new ticket. 

- Here, status is manually set by a person.

Comment: In that case, offload the processing of the message to a function and trigger the function via a thread 

```from threading import Thread
 
my_thread = Thread(target = <your function>)
 
my_thread.start()
```

Sending off the processing to a thread allows your other process to continue listening for messages. You can also just add the message to a queue which the thread (now running separately) checks at intervals and processes any messages it finds in it. The downside is that the thread is always running

Comment: I found the solution, using flask I just had to set
'''
app.run(threaded=True, port=5000)
'''
Apparently, flask had threading all this time and I was wasting my time looking for a solution. :D